# Android Kotlin no enter button on Keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, enter

I have a problem with no Enter Button on my Keyboard. Where can I set this or what should I do to have here enter Button??
Any Tips?

[image]

xml code to edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText           
            android:id="@+id/bookId"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/parameterBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/go" />
    </LinearLayout>              
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove singleLine attribute from xml

Comment: I dont have such attribute

Comment: share your xml code

Comment: I edited post and added xml code

Comment: use this inside edittext android:imeOptions="actionNone"

Comment: take a look at this attribute https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:imeOptions

Answer (score 1):

Just add `imeOptions` property to `flagNoEnterAction` in `editText` like below.

```
 <EditText           
            android:id="@+id/bookId"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction" />
```